# Find closest GeoJSON polygon to point when point lies outside of all polygons in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson

Using Elasticsearch, say I have documents of GeoJSON polygons. I'm using the percolator (ala [How to know if a geo coordinate lies within a geo polygon in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427121/how-to-know-if-a-geo-coordinate-lies-within-a-geo-polygon-in-elasticsearch)) to find if a point lies within a polygon. That works great!

Is there any way in Elasticsearch to determine

1. If a point lies outside of all polygons
2. What the closest polygon that to that point?
3. Return that polygon

Comment: It is possible to know whether a point lies outside of all indexed `geo_shape` polygons, however, since sorting `geo_shape`by distance [is not yet supported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13351) you'll have a hard time finding the closest polygon.

Comment: Bummer but makes sense, thanks for the link to that issue.