# Find distance from a point to the n closest polygons in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is similar to [Find closest GeoJSON polygon to point when point lies outside of all polygons in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558123/find-closest-geojson-polygon-to-point-when-point-lies-outside-of-all-polygons-in) but instead of returning *the* closest polygon, I'd like to return all *documents* that has a polygon closer than a particular distance (say 10 km). I'd like the distance to each polygon to be included in the result and it should be sorted by distance (ascending or descending doesn't matter).

A comment in the referred question pointed to a [github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13351) that has now been resolved (since Elastic Search 7.7) but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it based on the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html).

**Update**

After reading the [answer by joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643447/398441) I want to clarify that by "distance" I mean the closest distance to the nearest point of the polygon's border. Like what's described in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159225/postgis-closest-polygon-to-point) for PostGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `geo_shape` query with a buffered circle which will act as an umbrella that your polygons-of-interest will intersect. If they do, they match.
The only issue is that the "distance to each polygon" is somewhat arbitrary -- are we talking about the nearest point of a polygon's border? Or maybe its center?

I've only been able to come up with an implementation of the latter but it requires a secondary center field since scripted center computation would be too onerous.

Here's a visual:

[image]

Set up an index:

```json
PUT geo/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "polygon_field": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      },
      "center_field": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sync 4 polygons w/ their centers:

```json
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"geo","_type":"_doc"}}
{"polygon_field":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[16.391773223876953,48.20248146453242],[16.389713287353516,48.19939223822629],[16.39812469482422,48.19721822655714],[16.39812469482422,48.200422001027874],[16.395721435546875,48.20248146453242],[16.391773223876953,48.20248146453242]]]},"center_field":[16.393918991088867,48.199849845544776]}
{"index":{"_index":"geo","_type":"_doc"}}
{"polygon_field":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[16.340789794921875,48.207172155652366],[16.333751678466797,48.203625575146994],[16.337528228759766,48.199735494793444],[16.34490966796875,48.19882013883662],[16.34490966796875,48.20293911184484],[16.341476440429688,48.20682894891699],[16.340789794921875,48.207172155652366]]]},"center_field":[16.339330673217773,48.20299614724449]}
{"index":{"_index":"geo","_type":"_doc"}}
{"polygon_field":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[16.37014389038086,48.23370651063653],[16.36585235595703,48.23061916787409],[16.369457244873047,48.2286751898296],[16.37683868408203,48.23119091206881],[16.374778747558594,48.233592167930034],[16.37014389038086,48.23370651063653]]]},"center_field":[16.37134552001953,48.23119085023306]}
{"index":{"_index":"geo","_type":"_doc"}}
{"polygon_field":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[16.47777557373047,48.14936662796115],[16.466102600097656,48.143868849060205],[16.475372314453125,48.13562107648419],[16.494598388671875,48.13493370228957],[16.494598388671875,48.144097934938884],[16.47777557373047,48.14936662796115]]]},"center_field":[16.480350494384766,48.14215016512536]}
```

Search & sort by the closest (against the center) ascending:

```json
GET geo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "polygon_field": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "circle",
          "radius": "10km",
          "coordinates": [
            16.3704,
            48.21
          ]
        },
        "relation": "intersects"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "center_field": [
          16.3704,
          48.21
        ],
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "mode": "min"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've clarified the question, I did indeed mean the nearest point of a polygon's border when I talked about distance. If this isn't possible I would be happy to accept your answer. Sorry that I forgot this crucial part of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm afraid there currently is no `ST_Distance` alternative -- or it's poorly documented.